# Simple linear interpolation in $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Tags: numerical-methods

When doing simple linear interpolation on a data set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I just sort the points by one co-ordinate and then do piecewise interpolation between a point and its successor in the sorted data set.

1. How would I do this in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and generally in $\mathbb{R}^k$?
2. How would I know which points to "connect"? (In the two-dimensional case the sorting takes care of that.)
3. How complex would it be to calculate such simple interpolations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to triangulate the data set then do linear interpolation within each triangle (simplex, in higer-dimensions).

Comment: Is it also called *triangulation* for data sets of higher dimensions (my spatial imagination ends at three dimensions :P)?

Comment: Mostly, yes, although some people say *tetrahedralization* in 3d solid data, in contrast with 3d surface data, which can be triangularized.